# how to set LoadContentFrom kendo window in run time

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

i'm starter in kendo ui, i want use kendoUi window but i have some problem for use i write this code for create window

```
@(Html.Kendo().Window().Name("Details")
    .Title("Customer Details")
    .Visible(false)
    .Modal(true)
    .Draggable(true)
    .Width(300)       
)
```

in page i have some button , i want when user click in one of this button set `LoadContentFrom` dynamically with jquery. But I do not know how to do it. please help me. thanks all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try this:

```
   $("#yourbuttonID").bind("click", function() {
       $("#Details").data("kendoWindow").open();
   });
```

to load content to use:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Window().Name("Details")
    .Title("Customer Details")
    .Visible(false)
    .Modal(true)
    .Draggable(true)
    .LoadContentFrom("brand", "edit") 
    .Width(300)
)
```

Comment: thanks for asware me. but what 'kendoWindow'? i want load view.

Comment: it a refernce ta make sure it window

Comment: if want load view edit from controler brand and send 1 for parameters i write this  $("#Details").data("brand/edit/1").open(); but i get error, please help me. thanks

Comment: i get this error(i write this code in script tag),0x800a01b6 - JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'LoadContentFrom'

Comment: i explain problem, example i have 4 button in form when user click in button edit i want load view edit in window and send param to edit controler, when user click in add button i want load add view and ,...

Comment: explain problem, example i have 4 button in form when user click in button edit i want load view edit in window and send param to edit controler, when user click in add button i want load add view and ,...

Answer (score 5):

You need to get hold of the window object, set its `url` and pass in the query string to the url property. This works for me:

```
        var window = $("#Details").data("kendoWindow");
        window.refresh({
            url: '/YourController/YourAction/......',

        });
        window.open().center();
```

Additionally, you can pass in some data to the `action` as well:

```
        window.refresh({
            url: '/YourController/YourAction/......',
            data: { id: 10, enterpriseId: 88}

        });
```

Or you copuld just have a function to create the window on the fly and set it's content url with some parameter:

```
    function createKendoWindow(contentUrl) {
        $(document.body).append('<div id="Window"></div>');
        $('#Window').kendoWindow({
            title: "Log In",
            modal: true,
            resizable: false,
            width: 400,
            content: contentUrl,
            visible: false,
            minHeight: 350,
            animation: {
                open: {
                    effects: "expandVertical",
                    duration: 1000
                },
            },
            close: function () {
                setTimeout(function () {
                    $('#Window').kendoWindow('destroy');
                }, 200);
            }
        }).html('<img src="761.gif" />').data('kendoWindow').center().open();
    }
```

Comment: This seems a good solution. But I have a problem with loading the content from an MVC PartialView. The view has other Kendo widgets which are not displayed correctly because of JavaScript errors after loading the content. I don't know what's the problem here.

Comment: I got it working. I just removed all other windows from my View and only used the createKendoWindow() method. It's working great now. Thanks Mohammad

Answer (score 1):

You can use LoadContentFrom and specify Action and Controller.  The action will have its own View attached to it.  See [here](http://kirandhappuri.wordpress.com/2014/12/12/kendo-ui-window-a-modal-dialog-with-kendo-grid-mvc-controller-action-partial-view-and-ajax-calls-to-refresh-data/) for details.

Answer (score 1):

Can also use the [window.setOptions()](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/window/methods/setoptions) method to set the url dynamically. Useful if you do not want the content to load immediately, or need to specify more options.

```
var window = $("#Details").data("kendoWindow");
window.setOptions({
  content: { url: '/YourController/YourAction/......' },
});
// do other stuff...
window.refresh().open();
```

The url property is set in the **content** object:
[window content configuration options](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/window/configuration/content)